# Braces don't match with regex equals operator

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, regular-expression

```
function! s:foo()
    normal! yiw
    if @" =~# '\vf[0-9]b\('
        echom 'Matches!'
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> * :<c-u>call <sid>foo()<cr>

" f2b⣿(
```

When my cursor position is `⣿` and I press *, why doesn't it say 'Matches!'.
I just can't get any braces to match (`<`, `(`, `[`, or `{`).

I would also be very happy about any recommended references, as I `h regex` or `h =~` isn't really helpful, as it just covers the basics...

Comment: Does `iskeyword` contain these characters (`<`, `(`, `[`, `{`)? See [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word) for what `w` uses.

Comment: Okay wow that was stupid, of course that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `w`, motion, see [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word):

```
                                                        word
A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, <EOL>).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.
                                                        WORD
A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
```

So, you probably need to set `iskeyword`, or use `W`.

However, depending on what your actual use for this thing is, you don't need to copy the text. Use [`<cword>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3A%3Ccword%3E) (or `<cWORD>`):

```
    <cword>    is replaced with the word under the cursor (like star)
    <cWORD>    is replaced with the WORD under the cursor (see WORD)
```

So:

```
function! s:foo()
    let l:word = expand('<cWORD>')
    if l:word =~# '\vf[0-9]b\('
        echom 'Matches!'
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I love how you turned a stupid question into an answer where I still learned a lot!